# Apache LIMIT directive does not allow to see localhost project over LAN

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, 500-error, http-status-code-403

I want to allow to see my localhost project over the LAN using Apache [LIMIT directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limit) in **`.htaccess`**

my localhost project URL is `http://192.68.0.123/myproject`

below is the **`.htaccess`** part which cause problem

```
<Limit POST PUT DELETE>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 192.168.0.0/255
 Satisfy any
</Limit>
```

but it gives error

> ### Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> #### Error 500
>
> 192.168.0.123   Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

my **error_log** is

> [Fri Dec 26 11:18:36.183915 2014] [core:alert] [pid 4752] [client
>   192.168.0.123:38795] /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/.htaccess: The specified network mask is invalid.

my work around

- If I set `allow from 192.168.0.123`  it works only for my IP not over LAN
- If I set `allow from 192.168.0-5.0-255` then **it works fine** (expected) 
  but only the main page is coming, after login it gives **Access forbidden!403**

whereas it was advised to use `/` on [this blog](http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/) and many other SO answers

Does this (`/` to `-`) changed into **apache 2.4** ?

someone kindly explain the differences of these and proper valid syntax, I didn't find it on Apache documentation.

---

### another issue

When add **GET** in LIMIT option

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 192.168.0.0-255
</Limit>
```

then it gives error everywhere

> ### Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is
>   either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>
> #### Error 403 Access forbidden!

**errro_log** is

> [Fri Dec 26 11:34:05.840880 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 4752]
>   [client 192.168.0.123:39012] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution [from this article](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=5786)

change the line

<del>allow from 192.168.0.0-255</del>
to

`allow from 192.168.0.2/255.255.0.0`

> will lock Apache down to my internal LAN i.e. address range
>   *192.168.0.2* to *192.168.0.255* only with subnet mask of *255.255.0.0*

and it works with **GET** also, here is my final **`.htaccess`**

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
 Allow from 192.168.0.2/255.255.0.0
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 0):

The satisfy directive is intended to combine multiple requirements i.e. both from your subnet **and** a valid-user .

Leave that option out and you should have a more valid  configuration.

Also it is better to use your apache configuration file rather than .htaccess files.

Comment: already checked with removal of `satisfy` but error remains. And do not have access to Apache log on server that's why I used it on `.htaccess`